# Re-enable a chrome extension after disabling it with enable/disable method

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and programming in general, so apologies if this is a noobish question. I want to make a Chrome extension that is enabled on certain pages (YouTube videos, specifically), but is disabled on other "invalid" pages. Right now, it simply returns the URL of the valid page, but that is just for testing purposes. My popup.js code:

```
    var site;
    const isYTVid = /^https?:\/\/www.youtu\.?be(?:(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/(?:embed\/)|(?:\.com\/watch\?v=))(?:[^#\&\?]+).*/;
    
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
        site = tabs[0].url;
        document.getElementById('address').innerHTML= site;
    
        if (isYTVid.test(site)) {
            chrome.action.enable(tabs.id);
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML= "This is a valid tab";
        } else {
            chrome.action.disable(tabs.id);
            // document.getElementById('message').innerHTML= "This is an invalid tab";
        }
    });
```

However, after the extension gets disabled, it won't re-enable upon visiting a valid page. From my research, it seems that once the extension is disabled, it isn't possible to re-enable it from within the code, so I wanted to know if it is possible by using background.js somehow, or if there is any other way to do it. If there isn't, then is having the extension popup be a message to the effect of "This is an invalid page." the best solution, or is there another, more preferred option. I'm using Manifest V3, BTW.

Comment: That's because you should do it in the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, but simply copy-pasting this code into the background script and removing the document related lines doesn't seem to work, so what do I do in the background script?

Comment: The background script is event-driven so it should use an API event listener like chrome.tabs.onUpdated instead of an imperative call of chrome.tabs.query.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried adding the following script to my background.js file `const isYTVid = /^https?:\/\/www.youtu\.?be(?:(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/(?:embed\/)|(?:\.com\/watch\?v=))([^#\&\?]+).*/;

function tabUpdated(tabs, changeInfo) {
    if (isYTVid.test(changeInfo.url)) {
        chrome.action.enable(tabs.id);
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(tabUpdated);` However, it still doesn't get re-enabled. I don't think sending a message will work since the popup.js file is de-activated when the extension is disabled. Is the code in background.js wrong?

Comment: chrome.tabs.onUpdated, not onActivated.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've tried the following two versions: `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function tabUpdated(tabId, changeInfo, tabs) {
    if (isYTVid.test(changeInfo.url)) {
        chrome.action.enable(tabs.id);
    } else {
        chrome.action.disable(tabs.id);
    }
})` and the one in the  previous post with onActivated changed to onUpdated. I've also tried switching between tabId and tabs.id in both. No real luck. For a brief moment, it actually worked perfectly while I was busy elsewhere. Then I updated the extension from the browser and it was gone and I have no idea what made it work